# Looking for a word that fits for a young grown woodland

Tags: vocabulary, expressions

I'm looking for a word that represents a young wood of forest. In German, you would say "junger Bestand". What is the equivalent English expression - young stand, young stock or some other word?

Comment: sorry, in case that anyone knows an expression...

Comment: A young grove comes to mind if you mean the entire forested area.  A young stand could also work for a few trees within an area.  Sapling is a word for a young tree.  Can you further clarify if you mean a tree or a group of trees?

Comment: Thank you Michael, yes I mean it could be a few trees in a smaller area or even a reforested area (few hectars).

Comment: Possibly "new growth forest" or "new growth woodland".

Comment: For a plantation of trees - "afforestation".

Comment: I wonder if "a young woodland patch" works.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in a large forest where logging happened frequently. "New growth forest" is the term used for an area that had been logged and had new trees growing.